# Group by or add

Tags: mysql, sql

i would like to get only 1 row with the date:

```
select Datum, ZONE_2, 0 as SEEFRACHT

        from (

             select to_char(arch_p.ANKUEND_TERMIN,'dd.mm.yy') as Datum, Count (*) as ZONE_2
             from ARCH_PACKSTUECK arch_p
             where (arch_p.lbr_auf_nr like '%02')
             group by to_char(arch_p.ANKUEND_TERMIN,'dd.mm.yy')

             union all

             select to_char(ANKUEND_TERMIN,'dd.mm.yy') as Datum, Count (*) as ZONE_2
             from PACKSTUECK p
             where(p.lbr_auf_nr like '%02')
             group by to_char(p.ANKUEND_TERMIN,'dd.mm.yy')

             order by Datum           
             )
```

> ```
> DATUM |ZONE_2|SEEFRACHT
> 01.02.17  5   0
> 01.02.17  588 0
> 02.02.17  52  0
> 02.02.17  484 0
> ```

[image]

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select Datum, sum(ZONE_2) as ZONE_2, 0 as SEEFRACHT
        from (

             select to_char(arch_p.ANKUEND_TERMIN,'dd.mm.yy') as Datum, Count (*) as ZONE_2
             from ARCH_PACKSTUECK arch_p
             where (arch_p.lbr_auf_nr like '%02')
             group by to_char(arch_p.ANKUEND_TERMIN,'dd.mm.yy')

             union all

             select to_char(ANKUEND_TERMIN,'dd.mm.yy') as Datum, Count (*) as ZONE_2
             from PACKSTUECK p
             where(p.lbr_auf_nr like '%02')
             group by to_char(p.ANKUEND_TERMIN,'dd.mm.yy')

             ) as t
        group by Datum           
        order by Datum
```